# Exception dispatching input event

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do list view. My app is working in first tme opening but after backs to main menu it is not working again and giving the error on emulator "unfortunately app is stopped".

Here is my main.

```
public class ListMyJob extends Activity {
        ItemListBaseAdapter adapter;               //////after answers ı added.
        public void onBackPressed() {             //////after answers ı added.
                                                 //////after answers ı added.
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      //////after answers ı added.

    }                                           //////after answers ı added.
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> jobs = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();{   /////////////some list data /////////////////////}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = jobs;

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(ListMyJob.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intObj = new Intent(ListMyJob.this,ListMyExercises.class);  /////modified

                intObj.putExtra("description",obj_itemDetails.getItemDescription());
                intObj.putExtra("name",obj_itemDetails.getName());
                intObj.putExtra("imagenumber",obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber());
                intObj.putExtra("videonumber", obj_itemDetails.getVideoNumber());

                ItemDetailsWrapper wrapper = new ItemDetailsWrapper(obj_itemDetails.getChild());
                intObj.putExtra("exerciselist", wrapper); // i.putExtra("obj", new ItemDetailsWrapper(list));

                startActivity(intObj);
            }  
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting these errors on the logcat.

```
04-24 09:31:44.596: E/InputEventReceiver(2170): Exception dispatching input event.
04-24 09:31:44.596: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099660, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.jsupport.HealthyMe.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3403)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-24 09:31:44.676: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2170):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 09:31:44.676: D/AndroidRuntime(2170): Shutting down VM
04-24 09:31:44.676: W/dalvikvm(2170): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099660, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.jsupport.HealthyMe.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3403)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-24 09:31:44.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2170):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 09:36:44.811: I/Process(2170): Sending signal. PID: 2170 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099660, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.jsupport.HealthyMe.ItemListBaseAdapter)]

Comment: your listview data will be changed when you come back..

Comment: @tugba kaya have you solved the issue...i am getting the same issue in  listview

Answer (score 2):

use

```
onBakcPressed(){
  adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
}
```

Comment: ı made these changes. But this time, ıt does not wait all back buttons to go my app opening scene. once ı click the back. ıt stoppes the app.                                                          `public class ListMyJob extends Activity {
        ItemListBaseAdapter adapter;
     // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(listItems);
 public void onBackPressed() {
 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 
 }
 

    ArrayList<ItemDetails> jobs = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();{`

Comment: ı have edited the question code my whole code and changes with ı have made. I want to use back button on my app without any "unfortunately has stopped"